# Filter one dataframe using multi-index of another dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following two dataframes DF1 and DF2.  I would like to filter DF1 based on the multi-index of DF2.

```
DF1:
                            Value
Date        ID      Name       
2014-04-30  1001    n1        1
2014-05-31  1002    n2        2
2014-06-30  1003    n3        3
2014-07-31  1004    n4        4

DF2 (index = Date, ID, Name):
Date        ID      Name       
2014-05-31  1002    n2        
2014-06-30  1003    n3        

What i would like is this:
                            Value
Date        ID      Name       
2014-05-31  1002    n2        2
2014-06-30  1003    n3        3
```

To do this i simply use:

```
f_df = df1.ix[df2.index]
```

However, when doing this what i am getting is this (notice the tuple index)

```
                            Value

(2014-05-31, 1002, n2)      2
(2014-06-31, 1003, n3)      4
```

How can i achieve what i am looking for?  which is a resulting dataframes without a tuple index?

Answer (score 3):

In Pandas version 0.14 you can use `df1.loc[df2.index]`:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
# 0.14.0

df1 = io.BytesIO('''\
Date        ID      Name    Value   
2014-04-30  1001    n1        1
2014-05-31  1002    n2        2
2014-06-30  1003    n3        3
2014-07-31  1004    n4        4
''')

df2 = io.BytesIO('''\
Date        ID      Name    Value   
2014-05-31  1002    n2        2
2014-06-30  1003    n3        3
''')

df1 = pd.read_table(df1, sep='\s+').set_index(['Date', 'ID', 'Name'])
df2 = pd.read_table(df2, sep='\s+').set_index(['Date', 'ID', 'Name'])
print(df1.loc[df2.index])
```

yields

```
                      Value
Date       ID   Name       
2014-05-31 1002 n2        2
2014-06-30 1003 n3        3
```

I believe this is because as of version 0.14 [`df.loc` can accept a list of labels](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindexing-using-slicers), and `df2.index` is list-like:

```
In [88]: list(df2.index)
Out[88]: [('2014-05-31', 1002L, 'n2'), ('2014-06-30', 1003L, 'n3')]
```

Comment: i get the same result, first columns is a tuple/list of the index values, and the second column is the Value column from DF1

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: i am using pandas version 0.14.1

Comment: I've prepared a runnable example which succeeds using `df1.loc[df2.index]` and Pandas 0.14.0. Please modify the example so we can replicate the error.

Comment: I think it is a data issue(could not post actual data used cause 1000s of rows). I believe it has to do with when an index in df2.index is not found in df1, but not sure, will test later.  I was able to solve by using intersect